# How do I change Windows 8.1 safe mode language?

Tags: windows-8.1, language

When I reboot my win8.1 into windows recovery menu, everything (menus, command prompt, etc..) is in Russian. Is there a way to change the language to English?

Comment: I assume your using a Windows 8.1 Russian installation with the English language pack?

Comment: @Ramhound exactly, Sir.

Comment: Start Windows normally, open a command prompt as administrator, and run this command: `dism /online /get-intl & bcdedit /enum all` Then post here the full output.

Comment: @Ramhound http://pastebin.com/UTG9yzaJ